# How to use thrust to accumulate array based on index?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am trying to accumulate array based on index. My inputs are two vectors with same length. 1st vector is the index. 2nd vector are the value. My goal is to accumulate the value based on index. I have a similar code in c++. But I am new in thrust coding. Could I achieve this with thrust device code? Which function could I use? I found no "map" like functions. Is it more efficient than the CPU(host) code?
My c++ version mini sample code.

```
int a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,1,1,3,4,4};
vector<int> key(a,a+10);
double b[10]={1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5};
vector<double> val(b,b+10);

unordered_map<size_t,double> M;
for (size_t i = 0;i< 10 ;i++)
{
    M[key[i]] = M[key[i]]+val[i];
}
```

Comment: Thrust has efficient reduce by key implementations, but they require that the inputs are grouped in key order, and your data is not ordered. So your choices are sort or order by key, then reduce, or use something else. GPUs don't do random access well, it is very hard to achieve decent memory bandwidth utilization, which is key to performance in this sort of operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comment, the canonical way to do this would be to reorder the data (keys, values) so that like keys are grouped together.  You can do this with `sort_by_key`.  `reduce_by_key` then solves.

It is possible, in a slightly un-thrust-like way, to also solve the problem without reordering, using a functor provided to `for_each`, that has an atomic.

The following illustrates both:

```
$ cat t27.cu
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

// this functor only needed for the non-reordering case
// requires compilation for a cc6.0 or higher GPU e.g. -arch=sm_60
struct my_func {
  double *r;
  my_func(double *_r) : r(_r) {};
  template <typename T>
  __host__ __device__
  void operator()(T t) {
    atomicAdd(r+thrust::get<0>(t)-1, thrust::get<1>(t));  // assumes consecutive keys starting at 1
  }
};

int main(){

  int a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,1,1,3,4,4};
  std::vector<int> key(a,a+10);
  double b[10]={1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5};
  std::vector<double> val(b,b+10);

  std::unordered_map<size_t,double> M;
  for (size_t i = 0;i< 10 ;i++)
  {
    M[key[i]] = M[key[i]]+val[i];
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) std::cout << M[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  int size_a = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  thrust::device_vector<int>    d_a(a, a+size_a);
  thrust::device_vector<double> d_b(b, b+size_a);
  thrust::device_vector<double> d_r(5); //assumes only 5 keys, for illustration
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_k(5); // assumes only 5 keys, for illustration
  // method 1, without reordering
  thrust::for_each_n(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_a.begin(), d_b.begin())), size_a, my_func(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_r.data())));
  thrust::host_vector<double> r = d_r;
  thrust::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  thrust::fill(d_r.begin(), d_r.end(), 0.0);
  // method 2, with reordering
  thrust::sort_by_key(d_a.begin(), d_a.end(), d_b.begin());
  thrust::reduce_by_key(d_a.begin(), d_a.end(), d_b.begin(), d_k.begin(), d_r.begin());
  thrust::copy(d_r.begin(), d_r.end(), r.begin());
  thrust::copy(r.begin(), r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t27 t27.cu -std=c++14 -arch=sm_70
$ ./t27
4 2 6 13 5
4 2 6 13 5
4 2 6 13 5
$
```

I make no statements about relative performance of these approaches.  It would probably depend on the actual data set size, and possibly the GPU being used and other factors.

Comment: wow! Thank you very much for your answer! I need some time to test the performance.